# Goerli Eth being taken from my wallet

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp, hardhat, testnets

Every time I receive ETH from a Goerli faucet it is immediately transferred out of whatever wallet I transferred it to. At first I thought said issue was related to just one test account which had its private key published on a Github repository (bad practice I know however the wallet only ever holds test ETH), however this is now happening to all of my wallets, none of which have their private keys written anywhere, having said this no currency is being stolen from any of the same wallets on the Ethereum mainnet. What is going on here?

Here's the test wallet on Etherscan: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x7be95207a1a83ccb1919a20736ef3e8803fb0f1b

[image]

Comment: Very difficult to say. In any case you really shouldn't use the same wallets in mainnet.

Comment: I recommend move everything to a new wallet with a new mnemonic. If the mnemonic was leaked it is a matter of time other addressed derived from it will be compromised.